# jQuery UI effects in Kynetx sidetab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, krl

I have successfully had a jQuery UI effect take place on a page using Kynetx's jQuery UI integration.

However, I am having trouble getting the effect to work from within a sidetab. Here are the rules for my application. I'm hoping someone can point out what I am missing:

```
global {
  css  <<
         #tester 
         { 
             margin-left: 10px; 
             margin-top: 10px; 
             width: 80px; 
             height: 80px; 
             background: green; 
             position: relative; 
         }
       >>;
 }

rule tab is active {
select when pageview ".*" setting ()

 pre { 
        results = <<  
           <div id='tester'></div>
            >>;        
}
{
     sidetab() with pathToTabImage = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10762217/search-tab-images/tab2.png" 
               and tabColor = "transparent"
               and topPos = "50px"
               and message = results
               and divCSS = {
                             "z-index": 10000,
                             "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
                             "width": "200px",
                             "padding": "0px",
                             "imageHeight": "162px",
                             "imageWidth": "53px",
                             "-moz-border-radius": "5px"
                            };
              watch("#tester", "click");
           }



 }



 rule jeffect_on_click is active {
     select when web click "#tester"
        jquery_ui:effect("#tester","bounce","normal");


 }
}
```

I made sure to include

```
use javascript resource jquery_ui_js
```

in my meta tag.

Comment: I'm not real clear on what "the" effect is. What should it look like and what does it actually look like. Screenshots please if they are relevant.

Comment: @Mike Grace He is after the bounce effect.

Comment: @Alex awesome! Thank you! I'll let you tackle that one since I have a bit of a hate relationship with sidetab. : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. Currently, the runtime, specifically the `watch()` action uses, `.live()` to register event handlers.  `sidetab()` eats all event handlers attached with `.live()`. `sidetab()` eats them because `.live()` actually works by attaching your click handler to the `document` object, and then watches for the event to bubble up. When it reaches the `document`, it checks to see if the event was registered from the element(s) matching your selector, if so, it fires your handler. `sidetab()` kills this by calling `event.stopPropagation()`, which stops the bubbling of the event, so it never reaches the `document`, so your handler will never fire.

You can fix this by registering your event handler with the jQuery utility function, `.bind()`. `.bind()` will only register the handler for elements that already exist, but as long as you take care that the elements inside of your sidetab exist ***before*** you call `.bind()`, you will be fine.

Something like this:

```
$K("#tester").bind("click", function() {
  $K(this).effect("bounce", { "times" : 3 }, 300);
});
```

Let's put that in the context of an entire app, shall we?

To keep this example simple, we'll simply `emit` the javascript necessary to attach our handler and have the div bounce when clicked. This example is also [available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/720710):

```
ruleset a369x111 {
    meta {
        name "Sidetab->Events"
            description <<
                Sidetab jQuery
            >>
            author "AKO"
            logging on

            use javascript resource jquery_ui_js

    }
    global {
        css  <<
            #tester { 
                margin-left: 10px; 
                margin-top: 10px; 
                width: 80px; 
                height: 80px; 
                background: green; 
                position: relative; 
            }
        >>;
    }

    rule tab {
        select when pageview ".*"

            pre { 
                results = << 
                    <div id="tester"></div>
                >>;        
            }
        {
            sidetab() with pathToTabImage = "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10762217/search-tab-images/tab2.png" 
                and tabColor = "transparent"
                and topPos = "50px"
                and message = results
                and divCSS = {
                    "z-index": 10000,
                    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
                    "width": "200px",
                    "padding": "0px",
                    "imageHeight": "162px",
                    "imageWidth": "53px",
                    "-moz-border-radius": "5px"
                };
                emit <|
                    $K("#tester").bind("click", function() {
                        $K(this).effect("bounce", { "times" : 3 }, 300);
                    });
               |>;
        }



    }
}
```